# Micro Marines : Arming the Miniature Army

Tags: science-based, warfare, weapons

Using my desk-top buddies as inspiration, I am building an elite group of four inch high miniature soldiers, created to be air-dropped into a situation of dire danger to perform feats of daring espionage and destruction....

[image]

The first task I have is how to arm these guys to enable them to go into battle.  Obviously, scaling down real-world assault rifles just won't work for a variety of reasons (small projectiles, big air resistance).

So, what can I arm these guys with to give them some effectiveness when infiltrating and dealing with human scale installations and enemies?

Background: These are living, breathing miniature men, scaled down to roughly 4 inches high. They are not overly strong or have special abilities.   The illustration above is only my inspiration.  The method of the guys creation/miniaturization is outside the scope of this question.

Intended mission profile:  I have a strike force of 100 of these guys that I airlift within reach of their target from a drone and then airlift them back out again in the same way.  They're the ultimate in stealth attack.

Comment: Before arming them you should probably spend some time thinking about *what* they exactly are. Are they *plastic miniatures* that you drop onto your coworkers head while shouting obscenities? Are they somehow *magically shrinked humans*, maybe even your children? Are they *highly sophisticated robots that look like little people? Smurfs? - it's difficult to arm something if you don't know what you're arming :/

Comment: Ok, how strong / weak are they? And how light / heavy? Just a human flesh scalled down, or maybe some mammal of the approximately tight size, made humanoid?

Comment: I'm pretty much thinking of humans scaled down.  I'm willing to allow some handwavium if it makes for better reading (i.e. if reality proves too burdensome).

Comment: I sadly still can't provide any good answer as I am only in possession of two of the three example bobble-heads...

Comment: No need to arm them: deadpool can break anything even the fourth wall no easy feat despite his tiny stature, the Bobby beside him will be his sidekick passively boosts all of deadpool's SPECIAL and last but not least occasionally deadpool shot will line up perfectly which might occasionally summons a Mystery Stranger, none other than the guy posing as Spock and still trying hard for his Nobel price... together they are dead(ly)!

Comment: If we are talking about scaleddown humans, you don't really need to arm them. Our old foe the inverse square law is our friend this time. If you scale down a human being to 1/4th of its original size, its muscle strength will only become 1/2 of the original and so on. Your tiny soldiers will not only have superhuman strength for their size, but also superhuman agility. They will be capable of peeling of the flash of a regular humans bones with their bare hands and will be bulletproof. Of course they will be a lot weaker, then their regular size but they will have a lot smaller point of impact.

Comment: They would deadly poisoners and spies, until your enemies started keeping cats or dogs, then they are just the world's most expensive pet-food. "I swear Fido catches the weirdest rats."

Comment: "How do I arm my action figures", while having the potential to help people creating worlds, is phrased in such a way that it is not about building a fictional world - really, at all. There is some justification in "this is their plan.." but as written it's still not about world building. Voted to close.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want immediate results, equip them with mini syringes filled with some really nasty stuff. Any kind of neurotoxin should work, the ammount needed to kill a human is miniscule (see [poison dart frog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poison_dart_frog)). Some high-tech dartguns propelled with CO2 or similar gas would be perfect for the task. My problem with this approach is that it uncovers your little fellas preety fast, and once you know of their existence, they are not as dangerous.

Personally i would go with less direct approach. The small guys would be perfect for espionage and sabotage. Equip them with USB Killers, mini-cameras etc. Hack computers, take incriminating photos, deliver some [Polonium-210](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotopes_of_polonium#Polonium-210) to someone's tea and be gone before he even notices. This way noone will even know they exist. ([I mean it could just aswell be KGB Agents.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisoning_of_Alexander_Litvinenko))

Comment: KGB Agent as always are the 1rst being accused. Even when journalist obviously committed suicide with 2 bullet in the head.

Comment: Those mass suiciders are very dangerous people :)

Answer (score 5):

I'd go with poison.

Since they are very small, they cannot do much harm with conventional weapons, shrunk equally.
So I'd equip them with bows or crossbows and poisoned arrows / bolts or knifes.

Similar to the sting of a wasp on an allergic person, the poisoning can work pretty quick.

Answer (score 4):

As per the above answers, your best bet would be using their small size for stealth, and avoiding direct combat.

However, if they do need to protect themselves against people in case something goes a bit wrong, then how about a miniaturised anti-tank weapon? You probably couldn't have much explosive in it (if your men are 1/17 scale, then that's about 1/5,000 by weight). But a payload of several grams is more than enough for Ricin poisoning or similar, and by using a guided rocket the weapon can be kept relatively small and lightweight.

Answer (score 3):

Miniature men with training can be extremely deadly and subtle assailants. In infiltration and destruction of human installations I would suggest small, compact but very powerful explosives. Similar to C4 they can be detonated remotely and if each member of your miniature army possesses one of these explosives, I imagine it can easily take down any building and kill every one inside. This won't be discreet but if you detonate them after you are airlifted and no one notices them during the operation, it doesn't matter.

In the assassination of 1 specific individual, poison would be most subtle and effective. To kill a person, you only need a couple milligrams of ricin, even less of Botox.

Answer (score 2):

Wondering how to use your [Small Soldiers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0122718/)?

I'd focus on sabotage, espionage, and causing paranoia.

Directly damaging weapons don't fit their size - at best, a single-shot thing, but even as a smart bomb they wouldn't use their potential best that way.
They could overthrow governments using stuff that is forbidden by various conventions.
Of more PR-friendly gear, can't go wrong with melee.

Answer (score 0):

Various mischiefs:

- [lubricate the brakes of a train known to go downhill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Bernardino_train_disaster)
- inject a corrosion promoter under the protective layer of the cables of a [major suspension bridge](http://www.sfgate.com/bayarea/article/Bay-Bridge-designer-fears-leaks-are-damaging-main-6548506.php) - or just drill enough holes and let the water do the rest
- get into the switch-board control room (using AC vents, of course) and [switch down a power line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2011_Southwest_blackout#Events). Bonus point if you can switch off [9 of them](http://www.darkreading.com/threat-intelligence/project-gridstrike-finds-substations-to-hit-for-a-us-power-grid-blackout/d/d-id/1323788)

Answer (score 0):

Are these miniature robots...if so, they could carry high explosives and do a lot of damage, and never be discovered.
Small bullets wouldn't do much damage, but some well placed charges on volatile stocks would cause a chain reaction that could decimate an entire army base.